# Changing rows into columns in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

I have a table that looks like this in Excel:

```
|firstname |Greg     |
|secondname|Armstrong|
|firstname |Joe      |
|secondname|Bloggs   |
|firstname |Jane     |
|secondname|Doe      |
```

And I need to change it to look like this:

```
|firstname|secondname|
|Greg     |Armstrong |
|Joe      |Bloggs    |
|Jane     |Doe       |
```

I'm not particularly well versed in all the functionality that Excel has so I don't even know what to look for.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: unpivot - search that. Or transpose. Either way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Split one column in Excel into multiple columns of 55 rows](http://superuser.com/questions/554666/how-to-split-one-column-in-excel-into-multiple-columns-of-55-rows)

Comment: There are already several similar question here with good ideas, please have a look on them. (http://superuser.com/questions/583595/move-every-7-columns-into-new-row-in-excel?rq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/554666/how-to-split-one-column-in-excel-into-multiple-columns-of-55-rows, http://superuser.com/questions/617017/how-can-i-transpose-and-group-data-in-excel-2010?rq=1, http://superuser.com/questions/668063/pasting-from-several-rows-into-a-single-row-every-6th-cell?rq=1) If none of the solutions work, please share what have you tried and why that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the original table is in columns **A** and **B**, pick any cell and enter:

```
=OFFSET($B$1,COLUMNS($A:A)-1+(ROWS($1:1)-1)*2,0)
```

copy this cell across and down:

[image]

***Note:***

Using the right formulas, you can always map any single column or row into a 2-D table and any 2-D table into a single column.

Comment: Thank you! You are a genius. I would never have found this.

Comment: @insidious_elk  thank you for the feedback ...........there are many similar formulas to re-organize data ............ no *VBA* is needed.